# SQLite Error deny file-write-create

Tags: sqlite

help solve the problem. When you start the emulator is no problem when you start the application on the device does not work, gives an error:

Sandbox: MAPIMAGE deny file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Applications/3547CCCF-7A0D-4C01-AA41-18D72C686314/MAPOSM.app/maps/st.sqlite

Comment: is your sqlite file in the documents directory or in the applicaton bundle?

Comment: yes, [APP FOLDER]/maps/st.sqlite, add file project -> Create folder references for added folder.

Answer (score 0):

The write permission on to the database file is working only if the file is added into the Documents directory folder. So first make the file into the doc folder and then do the rest

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:nil];

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
#pragma mark - Helper methods
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

-(BOOL)dbOpenedSuccessfully
{
    if(sqlite3_open([[self dbPath] UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                   message:@"Error on opening the DB"
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        return NO;
    }
}






//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
#pragma mark - Query
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


- (void) executeQuery:(NSString *)strQuery
{
    char *error = NULL;
    if([self dbOpenedSuccessfully])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",strQuery);
        sqlite3_exec(_database, [strQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL,&error);
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"%s",error);
        }
        sqlite3_close(_database);
    }

}
```